# Output of dispatch is undefined

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have a login page (login.js), when the form is submited data gets sent using redux , dispatch but when i console.log user selector it shows undefined and i don't really know why. The ajax call work and resp.data.json show the data in saga.js.
Init state is defined so even before the ajax call i should be able to access to isLoading and errorMessage which i cannot even have access.

login.js

```
import React, { Component, useState, useEffect }  from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useParallax } from "react-scroll-parallax";
import { useTranslation } from "react-i18next";
import axios from "axios";
import "./Login.css";
import logoWhite from './img/logo-white.png';
import svgLogo from './img/log.png';
import { Helmet } from 'react-helmet';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';

import userActions from './redux/auth/actions';

  const {
    postToApi,
  } = userActions;

function Login() {

    const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
    const [password, setPassword] = useState('');

    const user = useSelector(
        state => state.user
    );

    const dispatch = useDispatch();
 
    const handleLogin = e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        var data = {};
        data.email = email;
        data.password = password;
        dispatch(postToApi(data));
        console.log(user); // Undefined
     };
 
     const { t, i18n } = useTranslation();

    return (
        <div className="login-page"> 
           <Helmet>
                <title>Espace Client - Développement de site internet à Antibes, Cannes, Nice</title>
            </Helmet>
            <div className="container">
                <div className="forms-container">
                    <div className="signin-signup">
                    <form  onSubmit={handleLogin} autoComplete="off" className="sign-in-form">
                        <h2 className="title">Identifiez-vous</h2>
                        <div className="input-field">
                        <i className="fas fa-user"></i>
                        <input type="text" value={email} onInput={e => setEmail(e.target.value)} placeholder="Adresse e-mail" autoComplete="off" />
                        </div>
                        <div className="input-field">
                        <i className="fas fa-lock"></i>
                        <input type="password" value={password} onInput={e => setPassword(e.target.value)} placeholder="Mot de passe" autoComplete="new-password" />
                        </div>
                        
                        <button type="submit" className="btn solid">CONTINUER</button>
                    </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="panels-container">
                    <div className="panel left-panel">
                    <div className="content">
                        <Link to="/"><img src={logoWhite} className="logo" alt="Création de sites Web vitrine" /></Link>
                        <h3 className="text-white">ESPACE CLIENT</h3>
                        <p>
                            Vous pourrez suivre vos factures, modifier vos informations personelles, trouver de l'aide...
                        </p>
                    </div>
                        <img src={svgLogo} className="image" alt="Création de sites Web vitrine" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Login;
```

actions.js

```
const actions = {
  POST_TO_API: 'POST_TO_API',
  POST_TO_API_SUCCESS: 'POST_TO_API_SUCCESS',
  POST_TO_API_ERROR: 'POST_TO_API_ERROR',

  postToApi: data => {
    return {
      type: actions.POST_TO_API,
      payload: { data },
    };
  },
  postToApiSuccess: data => ({
    type: actions.POST_TO_API_SUCCESS,
    payload: { data },
  }),
  postToApiError: error => ({
    type: actions.POST_TO_API_ERROR,
    payload: { error },
  }),
};
export default actions;
```

reducer.js

```
import actions from './actions';

const initState = {
  isLoading: false,
  errorMessage: false,
  data: []
};

export default function reducer(
  state = initState,
  { type, payload }
) {
  switch (type) {
    case actions.POST_TO_API:
      return {
        ...state,
        isLoading: true,
        errorMessage: false
      };
    case actions.POST_TO_API_SUCCESS:
      return {
        ...state,
        isLoading: false,
        data: payload.data,
        errorMessage: false
      };
    case actions.POST_TO_API_ERROR:
      return {
        ...state,
        isLoading: false,
        errorMessage: 'There is a problem'
    };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

saga.js

```
import { all, takeEvery, put, call } from 'redux-saga/effects';
import actions from './actions';
import axios from "axios";

function run(data){

  var actionUrl = '/pages/login';

  return axios ({
      method: 'POST',
      url: 'http://xzy/api' + actionUrl,
      data: {
        data
      },
      headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8', "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*", "Accept": "application/json" }
  });
}

function* postToApi(payload) {
  try {
    const resp = yield call(run, payload.payload.data)
    console.log(resp.data.json); // Data shown in the log
    yield put(actions.postToApiSuccess(resp.data.json));
  } catch (error) {
    yield put(actions.postToApiError(error));
  }
}

export default function* rootSaga() {
  yield all([
    takeEvery(actions.POST_TO_API, postToApi),
  ]);
}
```

App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { store } from './redux/store';
import Routes from './router';
import AppProvider from './AppProvider';

const App = () => (
  <Provider store={store}>
    <AppProvider>
      <>
        <Routes />
      </>
    </AppProvider>
  </Provider>
);

export default App;
```

AppProvider.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { ConfigProvider } from 'antd';

export default function AppProvider({ children }) {

  return (
    <ConfigProvider locale="fr">
      {children}
    </ConfigProvider>
  );
}
```

./redux/store.js

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import createSagaMiddleware from 'redux-saga';

import rootReducer from './root-reducer';
import rootSaga from './root-saga';

const sagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware();
const middlewares = [thunk, sagaMiddleware];

const bindMiddleware = middleware => {
  if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
    const { composeWithDevTools } = require('redux-devtools-extension');
    return composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(...middleware));
  }
  return applyMiddleware(...middleware);
};

const store = createStore(rootReducer, bindMiddleware(middlewares));
sagaMiddleware.run(rootSaga);
export { store };
```

root-saga.js

```
import { all } from 'redux-saga/effects';
import authSagas from './auth/saga';

export default function* rootSaga(getState) {
  yield all([
    authSagas()
  ]);
}
```

root-reducer.js

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import App from './app/reducer';
import Auth from './auth/reducer';

export default combineReducers({
  Auth,
  App
});
```

Comment: Hi where do you use login.js ?

Comment: Can you show the whole login.js file please

Comment: Sorry i just updated the post and added the whole login.js.

Comment: Hi thanks can you also show where you add the redux provider

Comment: I found the error in the useSelector, it had to be const user = useSelector(
        state => state.Auth
    );